# jQuery: Test if checkbox is NOT checked

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I have two checkboxes (in the future will have more):

- `checkSurfaceEnvironment-1`
- `checkSurfaceEnvironment-2`

Basically, I want to write an if statement and test if one of them is checked and another is NOT checked. What's the easiest way to accomplish the following:

```js
if ( $("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").attr('checked', true) &&
     $("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-2").is('**(NOT??)** :checked') ) {
        // do something
}
```

Comment: Use `||` not `&&` to check if *either* is checked. `&&` checks if *both* are checked.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

One reliable way I use is:

```
if($("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").prop('checked') == true){
    //do something
}
```

If you want to iterate over checked elements use the parent element

```
$("#parentId").find("checkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
        //do something
    }
});
```

More info:

This works well because all checkboxes have a property checked which stores the actual state of the checkbox. If you wish you can inspect the page and try to check and uncheck a checkbox, and you will notice the attribute "checked" (if present) will remain the same. This attribute only represents the *initial state* of the checkbox, and not the *current* state. The current state is stored in the property checked of the dom element for that checkbox.

See [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Umm... this will just set `checked = true`

Comment: @Pablo - Check my answer below, which I is also a reliable/apt option.

Comment: @PabloMescher Hey, can you please help me?
I actually want to determine which checkbox(es) is/are checked among several? And, enable/disable textbox next to it.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath sure, if you are using jQuery you just have to find a selector for the textbox relative to the checkbox and use my second example. It would look something like if($(this).prop('checked')) {
$(this).find("<textboxSelector>").attr("disabled", true);
}

Comment: shouldn't you use three `===` to compare with `false`?

Comment: @Stophface in this case this property will always be a boolean since it is a computed property and not a string, so you can get away with using ==. It is wise to always use === though since this is not always the case

Answer (score 102):

```
if (!$("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").is(":checked")) {
    // do something if the checkbox is NOT checked
}
```

Answer (score 34):

You can also use either jQuery [**`.not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method or [**`:not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
if ($('#checkSurfaceEnvironment').not(':checked').length) {
    // do stuff for not selected
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1b07bqsu/16/)

---

#### Additional Notes

From the jQuery API documentation for the `:not()` *selector*:

> The **.not()** *method* will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a **:not()**
>   *selector* filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Comment: !$("#checkSurfaceEnvironment").is(":checked") returns a boolean. It is true if the checkbox is not checked. $('#checkSurfaceEnvironment').not(':checked') returns an array of DOM elements. Testing this with 'if' returns 'true' even if there was no match to the selector and the array is empty. The only way your answer could be correct is if you tested i$('#checkSurfaceEnvironment').not(':checked').length, which will return 0 or 1.

Answer (score 24):

An alternative way:

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aayb9/) and here is the code, you should also use prop.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').mouseenter(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //$(this).prop('checked',false);
        alert("is checked");
    } else {
         //$(this).prop('checked',true);
        alert("not checked");
    }
});​
```

I commented out the way to toggle the checked attribute.

Answer (score 20):

I think the easiest way (with jQuery) to check if checkbox is checked or NOT is:

**if 'checked':**

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
// I'm checked let's do something
}
```

**if NOT 'checked':**

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
// I'm NOT checked let's do something
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple question deserves a quite simple answer. He simply asked how you check if a box is NOT checked, while most of the answers here are to check if it IS checked. Thanks for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 11):

```
if ( $("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").is(":checked") && $("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-2").not(":checked") )
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a more direct implementation like avijendr suggested.

I had a little trouble with his/her syntax, but I got this to work:

```
if ($('.user-forms input[id*="chkPrint"]:not(:checked)').length > 0)
```

In my case, I had a table with a class `user-forms`, and I was checking if any of the checkboxes that had the string `checkPrint` in their `id` were unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

Here I have a snippet for this question.

```js
$(function(){
   $("#buttoncheck").click(function(){
        if($('[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")){
            $('.checkboxStatus').html("Congratulations! "+$('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length+" checkbox checked");
        }else{
            $('.checkboxStatus').html("Sorry! Checkbox is not checked");
         }
         return false;
   })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0">
      Checkbox</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1_" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1">
      Checkbox</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" id="buttoncheck" value="Check">
  </p>
  <p class="checkboxStatus"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

To do it with `.attr()` like you have, to see if it's checked it would be `.attr("checked", "checked")`, and if it isn't it would be `.attr("checked") == undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Return true if all checbox are checked in a div

```
function all_checked (id_div){
 all_checked = true;

 $(id_div+' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { 
    all_checked = all_checked && $('this').prop('checked');
 }

 return all_checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
if ($("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1:checked").length>0) {
    //your code in case of NOT checked
}
```

In Above code selecting the element by Id `(#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1)` then filter out it's checked state by `(:checked)` filter.

It will return array of checked element object. If there any object exists in the array then if condition will be satisfied.

Comment: Although your answer might help, you should at least explain why. As it is, your answer has been passed into the Low Quality Posts moderation queue (which is where I am viewing it) I suggest you edit your answer to add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to check or unchecked condition

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ev-click" name="" value="" >

<script>
    $( "#ev-click" ).click(function() {
        if(this.checked){
            alert('checked');
        }
        if(!this.checked){
            alert('Unchecked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two way you can check condition.

```
if ($("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").is(":checked")) {
    // Put your code here if checkbox is checked
}
```

OR you can use this one also

```
if($("#checkSurfaceEnvironment-1").prop('checked') == true){
    // Put your code here if checkbox is checked
}
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the simplest way given**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#chk_selall").change("click", function () {

                if (this.checked)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                if (!this.checked)
                {
                    //do something

                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and in worked for me!

```
$("checkbox selector").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
       do what you need!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but still, this is a good way to do it:

```
if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")==false) {
    //Do stuff here like: $(".span").html("<span>Lorem</span>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#checkbox1").prop('checked') == false){
    alert('checkbox is not checked');
    //do something
}
else
{ 
    alert('checkbox is checked');
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21386940)

Answer (score 0):

```
var getVal=$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked"); // jQuery

var getVal=document.getElementById("checkbox_id").checked //JavaScript

if (getVal==true) {
// perform task
} else {
// perform task
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements all other answers.

Answer (score -4):

```
$("#chkFruits_0,#chkFruits_1,#chkFruits_2,#chkFruits_3,#chkFruits_4").change(function () {
        var item = $("#chkFruits_0,#chkFruits_1,#chkFruits_2,#chkFruits_3,#chkFruits_4");
    if (item.is(":checked")==true) {
        //execute your code here
    }

    else if (item.is(":not(:checked)"))
    {
        //execute your code here
    }

});
```