# Change disabled/enabled when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery

I want to combine these two jquery things: [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery) and [JQuery check if checkbox is NOT checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440128/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-not-checked)

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agreement"> I read all the information in the red box above and followed the instructions!
</label>
<br/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="submit">
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($("input[name=agreement]").prop('checked') == true){
        $("input[name=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $("input[name=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/32w5kcf8/

But it does not work.
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Just a side-note: id is better than name for identifying elements in the DOM.

Comment: Will consider this, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple solution
first of all you need to use jQuery library in jsfiddle to use jQuery's instructions :)

first of all check html cause I've added class and id attributes to inputs :)
here is a solution of your problem with jQuery

```
$(".agreement").on('click', function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(".send").prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $(".send").prop('disabled',true);
    }
})
```

[jQuery example](http://jsfiddle.net/32w5kcf8/8/)

and here is in pure javaScript

```
function checkboxed() {
    var agreement,send;
    agreement= document.getElementById('agreement');
    send = document.getElementById('send');
    if(agreement.checked == true) {
        send.disabled = false;        
    } else {
        send.disabled = true;   
    }
}
```

[javascript example](http://jsfiddle.net/32w5kcf8/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a change handler

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=agreement]").change(function(){
        $("input[name=submit]").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5ehv5Lt/)

Comment: Works, but why can't I use it the way I made it?

Comment: @Zoker you have the code in dom ready which will be executed only once on doc ready...  you want the method to be called when ever the checked state is changed

Comment: Is it also possible to toggle the value?
So if "unchecked" -> value="this button is unchecked" if "checked"->"submit"