# Alert if anything inside the Form is used and not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```js
$('form input').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    alert('The Form Not Empty');
  } else {
    alert('The Form Empty')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='get' action=''>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</form>
```

I want to track the form inputs, If the entire form inputs are empty, i alert **empty** once, If a single input is not empty, I alert **not empty**

I keep getting `Not Empty` on the checkbox, But it works ok on the `text` inputs.

Can I just track the form itself if it is not totally empty or not instead of the inputs?

Comment: Click on the first box, type something, blur, you get Not empty, go back to the input, delete the content and blur, you get empty. Main problem is the checkbox, the value is "on" checked or unchecked

Comment: @Huangism Oh, Blur actually helps here, But the problem form contains every type of inputs except the one with defined values like range or radio

Comment: To check the checkbox, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440128/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-not-checked for the input text, the change only triggers when you blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).val()` is not a good test for a checkbox, the value is always "on", which is not empty.

For checkboxes you need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('form input').change(function(event) {
  console.log($(this).val())
  if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='get' action=''>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't i use the `form` itself to check If it contains any value in it? I actually don't know how `form`s works, But I assumed That it collects all the data in something temporarliy.

Comment: No, you must look at each individual form control.

Answer (score 0):

HTML has a build in feature called `required` to alert the user that the form should not be empty. For your form it should look like this:

```
<form method='get' action=''>
  <input type='text' required>
  <input type='number' required>
  <input type='checkbox' required>
</form>
```

Comment: the inputs are not supposed to be required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `required` attribute for your form or inputs to make them mandatory, more informations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: the inputs are not supposed to be required.