# How to make an email field conditionally required in Formassembly

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, required

We are using Formassembly to create our forms and currently we have a form which is both used by internal and external users. There is a checkbox in the form which distinguishes between internal & external users. I need the code to check if the **"Internal"** checkbox is ticked or not, if the **"Internal"** checkbox is ticked the email field needs to be optional otherwise the email field needs to required. I assume it can be achieved by Javascript or please advise if there is any other way. I have no idea in coding but tried looking up online and tried to code but it doesn't work.  Please help.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>


{

//#tfa_78 is the checkbox

 

 
  if($("#tfa_78").is(":checked"))  { 

//#tfa_1 is the email field
 
    this.getField("#tfa_1").required = false;

    }

  else 
  {

    this.getField("#tfa_1").required = true;

  }

  });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `onblur` on your checkbox to trigger a JS function that check its status an then require or not your email input.
The `onblur` will be trigger each time the checkbox looses focus (so each time it will be changed or clicked).

```html
<input id="tfa_78" type="checkbox" onblur="mailRequired(this.checked)"></input>
<input id="tfa_1" type="mail"></input>


<script>
function mailRequired(checked) {
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementByID('tfa_1').required = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementByID('tfa_1').required = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt help! I could not get it work on Formassembly.

Answer (score 0):

Due to having JQuery, we can solve the problem as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//#tfa_78 is the checkbox

  $("#tfa_78").change(function(){

 
  if($("#tfa_78").is(":checked"))  { 
//#tfa_1 is the email field
    $("#tfa_1").attr("placeholder","Optional Email");
    $("#tfa_1").attr("required",false)

    }

  else 
  {
    $("#tfa_1").attr("placeholder","Requierd Email");
    $("#tfa_1").attr("required",true)

  }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="tfa_78" /> Local User
<br />
<input type="email" id="tfa_1" required placeholder="Requierd" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt help. Can I ask what is the syntax if the Checkbox is unchecked? is it ($("#tfa_78").is(":unchecked")??

Comment: your welcome. yes it works fine ? did you find any problem !? if my answer is correct checked it as correct answer.

Comment: It worked fine. I had no issues. I have already marked your answer as useful. Can you please let me know the syntax if the checkbox is not ticked?

Comment: I think [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440128/jquery-test-if-checkbox-is-not-checked] will help you.

Comment: I tried if($("#tfa_78").not(":checked")) it is not working :(

Comment: Hi Mehrzad. Sorry for the confusion, I want the email(#tfa_1) field to be optional if the checkbox (#tfa_78) is ticked and required when it is unticked. I tried changing "True to false" and "false to true" in your "If" statement. It is not working. But when I put it back it works.

Comment: try it ... if(!$("#tfa_78").is(":checked"))

Comment: I am confused and sorry for confusing you too. Can you please forget about my code it is a mess. All I need to do is to check if (#tfa_78) "internal" checkbox is ticked and if it is ticked, the email field(#tfa_1) should be optional. If the "Internal" checkbox is unticked, the email field(#tfa_1) should be required.

Comment: Hi Mehrzad.. I dont want "$("#tfa_78").change(function(){" I just want the code to check if the internal checkbox is ticked or not and make the email field required accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work. Here is my code. But what if I need it to work if the checkbox is not ticked? will it be  $("#tfa_78").is(":checked == false") ?

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

//#tfa_78 is the checkbox

  $("#tfa_78").change(function(){
  $("#tfa_78").is(":checked")  
  $('#tfa_1').addClass('required')
  });

});

</script>
```